# Cutting carbon-steel sheet with a sliding grinder

Tags: metal, metal-cutting, grinder

I am new to metalworking and I want to cut some 2mm carbon-steel sheet using my grinder and proper disk. My points are:

1. I can not afford to buy a plasma for awhile
2. I want to slice pieces of 800 x 200mm in triangle shape
3. buying flat bars doesn't solve my problem.

I want to cut 3 or 4 pieces per weekend and I my main question here is: Can I work using this tool without destroying it?
Because as a beginner I have the impression that this is too much stress on the tool. Thanks.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what you want to do, maybe a picture or two?

Comment: Be very careful of "where the sparks go" - grinder sparks are a classic source of construction fires, as they are hot and travel long distances, and if they land in a favorable environment (sawdust or other flammable/insulating materials) they can smolder for a long time unnoticed, than then burst into flame hours later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A right angle disk grinder with an abrasive disk will work for the task you describe. Expect to see the abrasive disk slowly reduce in diameter at first, then more quickly as it gets smaller. This is an aspect of the abrasive material sacrificing itself to move steel.

To prevent destruction of the disk, it is important for it to remain in the plane of the cut. You can purchase a tool into which your right angle grinder will clamp, providing this restraint, or you can build your own from a number of plans and instructions on the internet. I used search terms, "DIY right angle grinder cutting jig" and found too many to list.

There are variations using wood as the construction material as well as metal strap and sheet and plate. Your DIY choice obviously would be based on your skill set, tools and materials available to you. The purchase options vary in cost, yet another parameter to consider.

[image: right angle grinder jig]

The image above is from a randomly selected [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlmCIKA6N4c&vl=en) thumbnail. Videos of different construction options are plentiful.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fred. Your answer was pretty much clear and I did not know that abrasive disks works like this. Fortunately they are not expensive. Also thanks by the video! I will try to make a metal right angle jig and try do make my stuff more relaxed!

Comment: Yup - not going to overtax the tool at all - just accept that cutoff disks are an expendable you should buy 10 at a time. Thinner ones cut quicker (less metal to remove) but are easier to break because they are thinner. Try some of each to begin with, and always wear adequate personal protective gear, and leave the machine guards in place, so that you don't get hurt when one breaks in use.

Comment: thx for the update!